# Load new files only from FTP to BLOB Azure data factory

Tags: ftp, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy files from an FTP to Blob , the probleme is that my pipeline copies all files including the old ones. I would like to do an incremental load by only copying new files. how do U configure this. BTW in my FTP dataset the parameters ModifiedStartDate and ModifiedEndDate are not showing. I would also like to configure theses dates dynamically

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's some work to be done in Azure Data Factory to get this to work. What you're trying to do, if I understand correctly, is to [Incrementally Load New Files in Azure Data Factory](https://businessintelligist.com/2021/04/29/incrementally-load-new-files-in-azure-data-factory-by-looking-up-latest-modified-date-in-destination-folder/). You can do so by looking up the latest modified date in the destination folder.

In short (see the above linked article for more information):

> 1. Use Get Metadata activity to make a list of all files in the Destination folder
> 2. Use For Each activity to iterate this list and compare the modified date with the value stored in a variable
> 3. If the value is greater than that of the variable, update the variable with that new value
> 4. Use the variable in the Copy Activity’s Filter by Last Modified field to filter out all files that have already been copied

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. This solution is not possible for me because my source data is an FTP and there is no field for filtering by Last Modified